# Objective-C Pull to Refresh

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, rss

I'm trying to implement a pull-to-refresh feature on my RSS feed table. The list pulls normally when loading the app, but I essentially need to replicate that for the pull-down.

Could anyone help as to why the code isn't working?

```
#import "RSSTableViewController.h"
#import "RSSDetailViewController.h"

@interface RSSTableViewController () {


    NSXMLParser *parser;
    NSMutableArray *feeds;
    NSMutableDictionary *item;
    NSMutableString *title;
    NSMutableString *link;
    NSString *element;

}

@end

@implementation RSSTableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // RSS Settings
    feeds = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://external.example.co.uk/newpost/example.rss"];
    parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
    [parser parse];


    UIRefreshControl *refresh = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
     refresh.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Pull to Refresh"];
     [refresh addTarget:self
                 action:@selector(refreshView:)
                forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
     self.refreshControl = refresh;


}


- (void)refreshView:(UIRefreshControl *)refresh {
         refresh.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Refreshing news feed..."];

         // Refresh Logic
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://external.example.co.uk/newpost/example.rss"];
    parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
    [parser parse];


        // Set the timestamp
         NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
         [formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM d, h:mm a"];
         NSString *lastUpdated = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Last updated: %@",
                                  [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];
         refresh.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:lastUpdated];
         [refresh endRefreshing];
         [self.tableView reloadData];
}



- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {
    [refreshView endRefreshing]; //'Use of undeclared identifier 'refresh view'//
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return feeds.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"];

    return cell;
}



- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

    element = elementName;

    if ([element isEqualToString:@"item"]) {
        item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        title = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
        link = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
    }
}



- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {
        [item setObject:title forKey:@"title"];
        [item setObject:link forKey:@"link"];
        [feeds addObject:[item copy]];
    }
}



- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {

    if ([element isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
        [title appendString:string];
    }
    else if ([element isEqualToString:@"link"]) {
        [link appendString:string];
    }
}


-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSString *string = [feeds[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"link"];
        [[segue destinationViewController] setUrl:string];
    }
}
@end
```

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: What problem are you having with the posted code?

Comment: ""I'm trying to implement a pull-to-refresh feature on my RSS feed table. The list pulls normally when loading the app, but I essentially need to replicate that for the pull-down.

Could anyone help as to why the code isn't working?""

Comment: Repeating what you already put in your question doesn't further explain your issue. You already have code that processes the pull-to-refresh and reloads the table. Therefore, you need to explain what problem you are having wit the posted code.

Comment: Sorry - thought you'd missed the top bit. Straight to the point, the pull to refresh just doesn't work. If you see under 'parserDidEndDocument' there is a commented line regarding an error. I presume fixing this would fix the fact it doesn't actually 'pull-to-refresh'?

Comment: You don't the code inside `parserDidEndDocument`. The call to `[parser pase];` won't return until the parsing is complete. And you have code to reload the table there.

Comment: BTW - if you are going to post so much code and the problem is actually commented way down in the code, it would really help if your question pointed that out. Don't make people search tons of code looking for a comment.

Comment: So removing that broken line should fix it? And so it does!! But now it pulls the previous posts again. I presume I need to clear the table and then pull the refresh? How would I go about clearing the table?

Comment: Okay! Sorry about that!

Comment: Scratch that. Simply adding [feeds removeAllObjects] prior to the refresh logic allowed this to work. Well, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Code works fine
Needed to remove the line in `parserDidEndDocument` with the error.

I then had to add `[feeds removeAllObjects]` under the `//Refresh Logic` line to clear the current table contents.

Thanks guys.